# React Router V4 redirect based on user role

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-v4

I have two types of users `isEmployer` and `isCandidate`. When I login, my app is supposed to check the `role` of the user and then load the approprate routes plus redirect to the appropriate landing page. This all seems to be working correctly however the route only redirects on `login` or on `registration` if the user role `isCandidate`. If the user `isEmployer` the page doesn't change however the navigation options in the navbar do.

I can't see what I'm missing here. Any help?

Path:  `App.jsx`

```
const App = appProps => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <div className="bgColor">
        <NavBar {...appProps} />
        <Grid className="main-page-container">
          <Switch>
            {/* candidate routes */}
            <IsCandidate exact path="/candidate" component={CandidateProfileContainer} {...appProps} />

            {/* employer routes */}
            <IsEmployer exact path="/employer/dashboard" component={EmployerDashboardContainer} {...appProps} />


            {/* IsPublic routes */}
            <IsPublic exact path="/register" component={Register} {...appProps} />
            <IsPublic exact path="/login" component={Login} {...appProps} /> {/* Page not found */}
            <Route render={function () {
              return <p>Page not found</p>;
            }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
);

App.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  isCandidate: PropTypes.bool,
  isEmployer: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withTracker(() => {
  const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();
  return {
    loggingIn,
    isCandidate: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isCandidate'),
    isEmployer: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isEmployer')
  };
})(App);
```

Path: `isEmployer.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const IsEmployer = ({ loggingIn, isEmployer, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (loggingIn) return <div />;
      return isEmployer ?
      (<Component loggingIn={loggingIn} isEmployer={isEmployer} {...rest} {...props} />) :
      (<Redirect to="/login" />);
    }}
  />
);

IsEmployer.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  isEmployer: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func
};

export default IsEmployer;
```

Path: `isCandiate.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const IsCandidate = ({ loggingIn, isCandidate, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (loggingIn) return <div />;
      return isCandidate ?
      (<Component loggingIn={loggingIn} isCandidate={isCandidate} {...rest} {...props} />) :
      (<Redirect to="/login" />);
    }}
  />
);

IsCandidate.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  isCandidate: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func
};

export default IsCandidate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea is you can pass in a function that returns a component that is correct for each user state
such as component= { () => {some logic to determine which user then return the appropriate component} }
does that make sense?

I think this is one implementation not sure if it is the best

obviously the app will keep track of the state of the user which w.e global state container you use flux or redux etc..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Could you be explicit.

Comment: I hope I'm making a decent attempt to look at your code but something like...
`
    <Route exact path="/candidate" component={
    () => {
    //logic check state with if statement
    // return specific component like
    //CandidateProfileContainer
    } {...appProps} />
`